# Problema em RewriteRule (HTACCESS)

Tags: apache, htaccess

Estou com o seguinte código HTACCESS:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^customer/$ index.php [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

(Limpei o restante do código para simplificar.)

Na pasta a qual o HTACCESS está (não está na raiz), possui um arquivo **customer.php**

Quando vou testar, ao invés dele "jogar" para **index.php**, ele "joga" para **customer.php**

Se eu altero o código para, por exemplo:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^customers/$ index.php [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

ou

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^qqercoisa/$ index.php [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Ele executa com sucesso.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Ficou meio confuso, o que você quer fazer?

Comment: o que vc não entendeu, Rafael?

Comment: Como disse no código, eu simplifiquei/limpei propriamente para não confundir. Estou utilizando o RewriteRule para URL amigáveis... mas o propósito/dúvida não é o problema e sim o erro gerado (e explicado acima).